# Amazon S3 seems to be selectively ignoring SOME of my CSS

Tags: html, css, amazon-s3

As per the title, some of the CSS that I want to use on my website is being selectively ignored by Amazon's S3 service. I know the items SHOULD appear since they do appear on my local WAMP instance, but I am about at my wits end here. For example, I have a div as such:

`<div id="lineDiv"></div>`

With a CSS section devoted to it as:

```
    #lineDiv{
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    color: #FC4A1A;
}
```

and on my WAMP instance, it works, a red line appears. On the S3 instance, nada. Same with:

```
    tab{
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

and anything targeting a p tag.

Comment: You're using Amazon-s3... Why not provide a link to your server so we can connect and try to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: @TyQ. www.browningplusplus.com

Comment: It&#39;s a 403 issue with one of your css files. http://d1ntgvxye04p11.cloudfront.net/browningplusplus.css not sure if this is the main issue, but it&#39;s one of them.

Comment: Your question is nonsense.  S3 doesn't know or care about your CSS.  It's blob storage, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Three things to test:
1) Add a space between the end of the element selector and the curly brace. #lineDiv {}
2) Maybe give it a height and width? I can imagine a border needs to be bordering 'something'.
3) Shouldn't it be border-color?

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should help, you're right. However, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: No dice on all three. Thanks for the attempt though!

Comment: @CBrowning0791 Are any errors popping up in your Console? Could be a result of a 404 or of conflicting CSS code. Other than that, shouldn't be any reason they are different.

Comment: @TyQ.Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

S3 can't disable some CSS attribute. but verify if your CSS is on your S3 bucket. You have an HTTP error 403. That means your server can be reached and process the request.

Comment: This is his website: http://browningplusplus.com
Note: It's just a frame linking to his real website https://d1ntgvxye04p11.cloudfront.net/

It seems to be a 403 forbidden error.